# Will OpenGL ES 1 be obsolete in the future?

Tags: iphone

I am using OpenGL ES 1 for my iPhone app which is similar to a Paint App. I wonder will OpenGL ES 1 be dropped in the future? should I use OpenGL ES 2 for now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that OpenGL ES 1.1 will be dropped in the near future, it will probably be deprecated but not completely removed. Currently all OpenGL ES 2.0 devices will emulate the fixed function pipeline with shaders anyway and its not a real problem to keep this support.

But on another side: You WANT OpenGL ES 2.0! Shaders are extremely powerful and enable you to do things that are impossible or really really hard to do with the fixed function pipeline. Plus chances are that your code runs a bit faster on newer devices if it uses OpenGL ES 2.0 natively.